# iPhone Upload Sounds

Tags: iphone, uploading

Hey, I'm new to this site. I think it is great! Okay, here's the deal. I just downloaded Smule Ocarina. I was wondering how they made it so you can upload a song to the cloud. I might have an app idea that might incorporate this. How would I do this? What would I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would have to define a format to play a song, for example MIDI, so you can Upload a MIDI file, ( not very heavy ) to a database (like mySQL) , and then you can download it and play it back with a synthesizer or something similar. There are some open source mobile synths that I think could be able to play MIDI, but you would have to check that out.
[Mobile Synth Open Source](http://the-palm-sound.blogspot.com/2009/03/mobile-synth.html)

I hope this helps you a bit, your question is very broad though, so there are lot of ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks, this sent me in the right direction. Kind of a newbie question, but how can I connect the iPhone to the server with the database, and have it add a new sound to it? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also, how would I convert the user's taps to MIDI or another format? How would the music be created?

Comment: 1) You may have to write a simple web-service to do that. ( it's a possibility)
2) I think this is implementation dependent.